# Why make objects "callable" using magic methods instead of calling from object.property?

Tags: python

I'm going through a tutorial that defines the **len** and **getitem** methods to get an object's length and index respectively.

```
class Garage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cars = []

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cars)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.cars[i]


ford = Garage()
ford.cars.append('Fiesta')
ford.cars.append('Focus')
```

I kinda understand why we would want to do it, as it allows us to call these methods on the object itself, instead of the object.property:

```
print(len(ford.cars))  # len of object.property
print(len(ford)) # len of object

print(len(ford.cars[0]))  # index of object.property
print(ford[0])  # index of object
```

My question is: why do we even want to do that? Is there any benefit to calling these methods on the object itself? I would appreciate if anyone can shed light on this level of abstraction.

Comment: It allows you to hide implementation details. You don't know and don't have to know how exactly a `list` object works internally to get its length, you just do `len(lst)`. The same way, a consumer shouldn't need to worry about how your object stores data internally, they just want to call `len(your_obj)`.

Comment: It also allows you to treat objects generically, e.g. for things like `sorted(garages, key=len)`…

Comment: The "why" and "whether" will strongly depend on the case. I dare say this example is meant for simplicity, not for reasonability. A more complex example would be harder to teach, but demonstrate the need better. Consider: What if the garage contained both cars and motorcycles?

Comment: So more than just that level of abstraction, it also allows for flexibility and reusability. Is this something we should actively do when creating class methods? From an implementation perspective, doesn't it seem a bit implicit?